# Groovy Date Formatting

Tags: java, string, date, object, groovy

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import groovy.time.TimeCategory
def startDate = 'Monday, May 11 2015'
def today = new Date().format( 'EEEE, MMM dd yyyy' )
def today1 = quantityService.normalizeAndFormat(today, DatumType.DATE, 
Formatters.DATE_IN_WORDS)
def diff = today1.minus(startDate);
```

The startDate is a string extracted from the database. And is formatted exactly like today1 is formatted above to produce 'Monday, May 11 2015'. I am unable to perform the subtract operation to obtain the value of the variable diff. Can you please guide me on how can I obtain the value of diff in the same format like startDate? Currently, the operation doesn't work probably because startDate is a string and today1 is a date object.

Comment: Check the case of the [format letters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) in the format string. `E` = Day name in week *(good)*, `M` = Month in year *(good)*, `D` = Day in year ***(WRONG!)***, `Y` = Week year ***(WRONG!)***

Comment: What do you believe `String.minus(String)` means, and why do you believe there even is a method for that? --- What do you believe the value of subtracting two dates from each other is, and why do you believe that value can be formatted like a date?

Comment: We can't see what values `today` and `today1` has. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and **Verifiable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for pointing out the mistake of dd and yyyy. I made the change in the initial question. Secondly, I want to subtract date from a date. not string from a string.

Comment: So why are you trying to subtract string from string? Don't you know how to parse a string into a date object? Is *that* your question?

Comment: If you're trying to find out the length of time between the two dates (for example, the number of days between), the `java.time` API has good support for that and I would assume that Groovy can access it. `java.util.Date` should not be used in new code.

Comment: As @DavidConrad said (or may have intended), the `Date` class is poorly deigned and long outdated. Using JDBC 4.2 or later (which you prabably are) you can fetch a `LocalDate` directly out of your database. And then use `ChronoUnit` to find the difference between dates. Both mentioned classes are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Well said, @OleV.V.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Use modern *java.time* classes, not the terrible legacy classes. Never use `Date` or `DateFormat` or `SimpleDateFormat`.

Example code in Java syntax:

```
Period
.between(
    LocalDate.parse( 
        "Monday, May 11 2015" , 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEEE, MMM d uuuu" , Locale.US )
    ) ,
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) )
)
.toString() ;
```

> P3Y8M18D

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were obsoleted years ago by the *java.time* classes, with the adoption of JSR 310.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

## `DateTimeFormatter`

Define a formatting pattern to match your input. (Java syntax)

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEEE, MMM d uuuu" , Locale.US ) ;
String input = "Monday, May 11 2015" ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 2015-05-11

## Elapsed time

To calculate elapsed time as years-months-days, use `Period`. For days (24-hour chunks of time, not calendar days), hours, and seconds, use `Duration`.

```
Period p = Period.between( ld , today ) ;
```

> p.toString(): P3Y8M18D

That string in standard ISO 8601 formats means “three years, eight months, and eighteen days”.

See the above [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/kP4k6p).

There is no localization feature in *java.time* to represent a `Period` or `Duration` with words. Instead, you can generate your own string.

```
String output = p.getYears() + " years, " + p.getMonths() + " months, " + p.getDays() + " days" ; // Obviously, you could get fancier by checking for zero or singular values and then adjust the text.
```

## ISO 8601

Avoid exchanging date-time values using localized formats such as that seen in your input. Instead, when exchanging date-time values as text, always use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. They were wisely designed to avoid ambiguity. They are easy to parse by machine, and easy to read by humans across cultures.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify any formatting pattern.

For a date-only value, the standard format is YYYY-MM-DD such as `2019-01-23`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2019-01-23" ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).